# Recursion seems to be working only to some level of depth - how to debug such problems?

Tags: c++, recursion

Im currently writing a program to draw the Sierpinski carpet using recursion. The code of my program is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

const int L = 4;
const int N = 81;
unsigned char output[N][N][3];

void prepareBoard()
{
    for (size_t y = 0; y < N; y++)
    {
        for (size_t x = 0; x < N; x++)
        {
            output[y][x][0] = 0;
            output[y][x][1] = 0;
            output[y][x][2] = 0;
        }
    }
}

void drawRed(int x, int y)
{
    output[x][y][0] = 255;
    output[x][y][1] = 0;
    output[x][y][2] = 0;
}

void drawCarpet(int y, int x, int length, int l)
{
    if (l < L)
    {
        int x1, x2;
        int part = length / 3;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < length; j++)
            {
                if (i > part && i < part * 2 && j > part && j < part * 2)
                {
                    drawRed(i+x, j+y);
                }
            }
            x1 = x + part;
            x2 = x + part * 2;
            drawCarpet(x, x, part, l + 1);   // 0 0
            drawCarpet(x1, x, part, l + 1);  // 9 0
            drawCarpet(x2, x, part, l + 1);  // 17 0
            drawCarpet(x, x1, part, l + 1);  // 0 9
            drawCarpet(x2, x1, part, l + 1);  // 0 17
            drawCarpet(x, x2, part, l + 1); // 9 17
            drawCarpet(x1, x2, part, l + 1); //
            drawCarpet(x2, x2, part, l + 1); //
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("output.ppm", "wb");
    fprintf(fp, "P6\n %s\n %d\n %d\n %d\n", "# ", N, N, 255);

    prepareBoard();
    drawCarpet(0, 0, N, 0);

    for (size_t y = 0; y < N; y++)
    {
        for (size_t x = 0; x < N; x++)
        {
            fwrite(output[y][x], 1, 3, fp);
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

How i launch the function:

```
drawCarpet(0, 0, 243, 0);
```

The issue is that the function works correctly up to the second depth - then it starts working on only two of the "subsquares". This is the output the the program.[image: outputimg]

I'd welcome any suggestions, especially on ways to approach debugging issues like this one. My algorithim for finding the pixels in the middle is also suboptimal and I'd love some suggestions on it too.

Comment: Looks like this is a good candidate for debugging. The error isn't that far in and it's consistent. You should be able to tear this sucker apart by stepping through the function a few times, looking for unexpected behaviour.

Comment: i have fixed it; depending on x on both new x and new y was the flaw.

Comment: x1 = x + part;
            y1 = y + part;
            x2 = x + part * 2;
            y2 = y + part * 2;

            drawCarpet(x, y, part, l+1);
            drawCarpet(x1, y, part, l+1);
            drawCarpet(x2, y, part, l+1);
            drawCarpet(x, y1, part, l+1);
            drawCarpet(x2, y1, part, l+1);
            drawCarpet(x, y2, part, l+1);
            drawCarpet(x1, y2, part, l+1);
            drawCarpet(x2, y2, part, l+1);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't tested it but I believe that the problem is that in the recursion calls - you don't use `y`.

```
        x1 = x + part;
        x2 = x + part * 2;
        drawCarpet(x, x, part, l + 1);  // why no dependency on y?
        drawCarpet(x1, x, part, l + 1);  
        drawCarpet(x2, x, part, l + 1); 
        drawCarpet(x, x1, part, l + 1);  
        drawCarpet(x2, x1, part, l + 1);  
        drawCarpet(x, x2, part, l + 1); 
        drawCarpet(x1, x2, part, l + 1); 
        drawCarpet(x2, x2, part, l + 1);
```

It should be something like:

```
        x1 = x + part;
        x2 = x + part * 2;
        y1 = y + part;
        y2 = y + part*2;
        drawCarpet(x, y, part, l + 1);
        drawCarpet(x1, y, part, l + 1);  
        drawCarpet(x2, y, part, l + 1); 
        drawCarpet(x, y1, part, l + 1);  
        drawCarpet(x2, y1, part, l + 1);  
        drawCarpet(x, y2, part, l + 1); 
        drawCarpet(x1, y2, part, l + 1); 
        drawCarpet(x2, y2, part, l + 1);
```

Comment: That was exactly the problem, I've figured it out in kinda the same time :). Thank you for spending your time on this!